# Backup personal info/files for move to new server

Tags: server

I develop locally with windows but deploy to a ubuntu 16.04 VPS. I'm thinking of moving to a different VPS company, and to so I assume I will have to create a new ubuntu server and upload all my files again. Is there a way to create an image of my personal files to make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

From the current VPS, you could create a tarball of your home dir:

```
cd ~ && tar czf myhome.tgz ./
```

Then on the new VPS, you could unpack this tarball:

```
cd ~ && tar xzf myhome.tgz
```

You might consider unpacking to a tmp directory first and then copying only what you need:

```
mkdir tmp; tar xzf myhome.tgz -C tmp
```

Comment: That looks interesting